# Spring transaction annotation

Tags: spring

I have a method `aaa`, it calls method `bbb` and `ccc`.

If there is a problem in `bbb` or `ccc`, I want to rollback.

I put for method `aaa` this annotation

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED),
```

do I need to put the same value in term of annotation for method `bbb` and `ccc` or I can use only this?

```
@Transactional
```

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation

Comment: that don't answer the question, do i need to put PROPAGATION_REQUIRED for bbb and ccc or i can use only transactional.

Comment: That's why it is not an answer but a comment. Did you read and understand the Spring documentation about transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just required to put `@Transactional` in aaa method and you don't have to put `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)` to bbb and ccc methods because
Spring transaction will handle by itself and takes this property as a default. If you want to isolate bbb method from this transaction started by aaa then put `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on bbb method.